# Bootstrap column width adjustments

Tags: css, razor, bootstrap-4

I am new to using Bootstrap. I tried adjusting a 3-coulmn row to fit, with the last column divided into another 3, but it overlaps and having difficulty in making it look right.

[image: see Picture]

My cshtml for the 1st row:

```
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
            <strong>Last Name</strong> <span class="required">*</span>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Patient_Lastname, new { @class = "text-primary", required = "required" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
            <strong>First Name</strong> <span class="required">*</span>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Patient_Firstname, new { @class = "text-primary", required = "required" })
        </div>
       <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
            <strong>birth</strong> <span class="required">*</span>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.YearOfBirth, Enumerable.Range(1900, 119).Select(i => new SelectListItem { Value = i.ToString(), Text = i.ToString() }),
           "--Year--", new { @class = "form-control", style = "width: 90px; height:30px;", required = "required" })
        </div> 
        <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
            <strong>Month</strong> <span class="required">*</span>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.YearOfBirth, Enumerable.Range(1, 12).Select(i => new SelectListItem { Value = i.ToString(), Text = i.ToString() }),
           "--Month--", new { @class = "form-control", style = "width: 90px; height:30px;", required = "required" })
        </div> 
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
            <strong>Day</strong> <span class="required">*</span>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.YearOfBirth, Enumerable.Range(1, 31).Select(i => new SelectListItem { Value = i.ToString(), Text = i.ToString() }),
           "--Day--", new { @class = "form-control", style = "width: 80px; height:30px;", required = "required" })
        </div> 
    </div>
```

The 2nd and 3rd row are straight forward with col-md-4

Could you help me fix this ?

TIA
Ron.

Comment: Anyway you can just post the HTML?

Comment: Does the issue correct itself if you make the window bigger?  If so then it just means one of those elements is too big to have a continuous flow and therefore something has to get bumped.  Keep in mind your rows will have gutters(-15 margin) and columns by default will have a padding of 10px.  You could try to reduce that padding to possibly fix the issue.  Also, not sure if this will help but usually when I am wanting to create a layout like yours I try to use form-row class and form-group classes instead of just row and col.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is the input filled width is bigger than available try resizing it.

Comment: then the whole page for the input width column gets resized, which looks messier..

Answer (score 0):

There is no fixed layout you have to follow so that your screen will look nice automatically! It's your job to try and experiment what's the best to fit your need.

Obviously there is no way for `col-sm-1` to fit a dropdown perfectly so you have to think of different layouts for different breakpoints. And *bootstrap* has many [nice CSS classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints) you can use out of the box already for that purpose.

### Extra Small Devices

For extra small devices, you might still be able to put year, month and day dropdown in a single row.

#### HTML Structure

```html
<form>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group">Last Name Label & Input</div>
        <div class="form-group">First Name Label & Input</div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col">Year Label & Input</div>
                <div class="form-group col">Month Label & Input</div>
                <div class="form-group col">Day Label & Input</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I used `.form-row` here instead of `.row` because it gives you [tighter gutters](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/forms/#form-row) between columns.
`.form-group` is used to give each input group a nice `margin-bottom`.
Use of `.col` is to give you [auto width](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/#equal-width).

#### How it looks like

[image]

Now you have a layout that works for extra small devices. You kind of start building up from this layout for each different devices with different screen sizes and **add** necessary CSS classes.

### Small Devices

For small devices, you might want to put last name and first name input as 2 columns in a row.

#### HTML Structure

```html
<form>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-sm-6">Last Name Label & Input</div>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-6">First Name Label & Input</div>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col">Year Label & Input</div>
                <div class="form-group col">Month Label & Input</div>
                <div class="form-group col">Day Label & Input</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

See those `.col-sm-*` classes are added?

#### How it looks like

[image]

**...**

**...**

**...**

### Extra Large Devices

#### HTML Structure

```html
<form>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-xl-4">Last Name Label & Input</div>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-xl-4">First Name Label & Input</div>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-12 col-xl-4">
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col">Year Label & Input</div>
                <div class="form-group col">Month Label & Input</div>
                <div class="form-group col">Day Label & Input</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

#### How it looks like

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the resolution for this problem @David Liang